# Replace exe file when application is running

Tags: c#, replace, exe

I have simple question - is it possible, to replace *.exe file (application file), when it's running? I mean i know that i cannot do that when app is running, but maybe it's possible to do something like:
do application.shutdown()
replace oldExe -> newExe
application.restart().

Comment: Is this some kind of auto-upgrade ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes, it is auto update. First i need to download all files(done), then apply database, dll updates(done), and in the end replace exe files. Ill try with command prompt with parameters then :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a helper application. You will run this "helper" application when you need it, and it can monitor/replace the main application when it has been closed. Once replaced, the helper application can launch your main application again.

You can also run command line arguments to your helper app, telling it what you need it to do.