# C# - How to get real file path (After it was moved)

Tags: c#

If I move application itself somewhere(While it's still running).

When I use

```
Application.Executablepath
```

It still shows me old path instead of new one!

I have to restart the application to get new path.Is there any way how to get REAL CURRENT path ?

```
Application.Startuppath 
Application.Executablepath
```

shows only path where did file started, but not the current path.

Comment: How do you move your application while it's running?

Comment: Your application moves itself? That sounds pretty suspicious....

Comment: How is it getting moved while running?

Comment: Sounds like you're making a virus that moves itself in order to stay hidden...

Comment: I cannot imagine any scenario in which what you are doing can be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

> [MSDN: Application.ExecutablePath Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath(v=vs.110).aspx):
>
> Gets the path for the executable file that **started** the application, including the executable name.

If you move the executable at runtime (and even if that succeeds, you [don't want to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695496/rename-a-running-executable-exe-file)), that doesn't change.

Save the new location in your application and refer to that.

If your actual question is *"How to update an assembly for a running c# process (AKA hot deploy)?"*, then [see that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335755/how-to-update-an-assembly-for-a-running-c-sharp-process-aka-hot-deploy).

Comment: Good advice here.  Anything that involves renaming/moving an application while it's running qualifies as a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: I want to make file that can't be moved.. So I don't know the new path. Is there any way how to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.